# How to make your 3D model have onclick events and display it on your website?

Tags: javascript, java, php, css, web

So i am trying to make my human body 3D model to rotate and have onclick events and use that on my website?
It should look similar to this: http://www.healthline.com/human-body-maps/male

Comment: I suggest learning the power of the Famous Engine. They fused WebGl and Dom under one api call. And built the engine with Physics and other stuff similar to what you would find in videogame engines. I've seen them do onclick events for 3d objects at a few of their DemoDays. 

Their site is http://famous.org/

Comment: You can also join their slack channel and maybe have someone help. I know you can create a wrapper and add a Famous Element anywhere in your applications html.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit to unspecific, but maybe the [WebGL Experiments](https://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl) or the [Unity3D webplayer](https://unity3d.com/webplayer) could give further hints.